# ТЕСТ по русскому языку

Tags: деепричастия

Укажите деепричастие несовершенного вида 
А) Пообедав . В) Разойдя . С) Пройдя.  Д) Рисуя . Е) Спасши

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос - явное домашнее задание

Comment: Было бы корректнее голосовать за закрытие вопроса ДО того, как на него был дан хотя бы один ответ.

Comment: Матвей Дёмин, это нелогично. По вашей идее получается, что вопрос с любым ответом и закрывать нельзя.

Comment: Значит, я неточно сформулировал свою мысль в комментарии. Отредактированный вариант:  Было бы корректнее голосовать за закрытие вопроса ДО того, как на него был дан правильный ответ.

Comment: Во-первых, закрытие вопроса показывает что подобные вопросы не приветствуются на сайте. Во-вторых, в закрытые вопросы нельзя добавлять новые ответы. К тому же, "правильный ответ" может быть дан до того как участники сайта успели заметить "неправильный вопрос".

Answer (score 3):

Деепричастия "разойдя" в русском языке нет. "Пообедав",  "пройдя", "спасши" - деепричастия совершенного вида. Только "рисуя" - деепричастие несовершенного вида.
Если имелось в виду деепричастие "разойдясь", то оно - совершенного вида.